# Is it possible to use Synapse without Axis2, to make ReST and SOAP calls, possibly with CXF and/or Jersey?

Tags: apache, rest, soap, apache-axis, apache-synapse

I am tasked with coming up with a way of using Synapse ESB without Axis2, basically to make ReST and SOAP calls to webservices.

Is there CXF support, for example?

I searched a lot but could not find a decent example which doesn't use Axis2, for ReSTful calls. It would be great if I could find a way using either CXF or Jersey..

Any idea anyone? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can replace axis2 by CXF..Synapse uses axis2 as its underlying SOAP engine